# Programmatically select a row in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, row, selected

When the application is started, none of the rows is selected. But I would like to show that the first row is already selected.

How to do this? Do I need to set the color of a row in `JTable`?

Update:
I tried table.setRowSelectionInterval(0,0). I know it should work, but there is an error message:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Row index out of range
    at javax.swing.JTable.boundRow(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JTable.setRowSelectionInterval(Unknown Source)
    at cpn_gui.OptPanel.createForm(OptPanel.java:124)
    at cpn_gui.OptPanel.<init>(OptPanel.java:50)
    at cpn_gui.Login$1.actionPerformed(Login.java:62)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You can do it calling [setRowSelectionInterval](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setRowSelectionInterval(int,%20int)) :

```
table.setRowSelectionInterval(0, 0);
```

to select the first row.

Comment: Please check the updates in my post. I posted an error message. What could be wrong?

Comment: My code looks as follows: QueryTableModel tableModel = new QueryTableModel();
JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
table.setRowSelectionInterval(0, 0);

Comment: Before calling table.setRowSelectionInterval(0, 0) you have to make sure that at least a row is present in the table, otherwise you will get this error. Call table.setRowSelectionInterval(0, 0) after filling the table ...

Answer (score 14):

It is an old post, but I came across this recently

**Selecting a specific interval**

As @aleroot already mentioned, by using

```
table.setRowSelectionInterval(index0, index1);
```

You can specify an interval, which should be selected.

**Adding an interval to the existing selection**

You can also keep the current selection, and simply add additional rows by using this here

```
table.getSelectionModel().addSelectionInterval(index0, index1);
```

This line of code additionally selects the specified interval. It doesn't matter if that interval already is selected, of parts of it are selected.

Comment: This is more general answer, that covers both consecutive and non-consecutive row selection. It worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

You use the [available API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setRowSelectionInterval%28int,%20int%29) of `JTable` and do not try to mess with the colors.

Some selection methods are available directly on the `JTable` (like the `setRowSelectionInterval`). If you want to have access to all selection-related logic, the [selection model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectionModel%28%29) is the place to start looking

Comment: I tried table.setRowSelectionInterval(1,1), but it says that the "Row index out of range", although the table was already populated from DB. Any ideas?

Comment: As almost everything in Java, numbering starts from row 0 and not row 1. So change it to `setRowSelectionInterval(0,0)`